# Async method result arrive too late so it return a wrong values

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I created a method that makes two `async` calls.
Method must return value so I have `return` when get data and `return` at the end which is some default value.
The problem is when I make second call to service I wait it result but the default `return` at the end of the method is executed first and when second call result arrive I can't do anything with it as it is too late.
This code is in web api which is called by web page.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeMethod()
{
   try
   {
       await login...;
       await doSomething....ContinueWith(x => {
       if (x.IsCompleted == true)
       {
           oneMoreAsyncCall.ContinueWith(r =>
           {    
               if (r.IsCompleted == true)
               {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someData); // Hit second!
               }                                
       }
       }

   }
   catch {}

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther); // Hit first!
}
```

Comment: Why mixing `async/await` with `ContinueWith`?

Comment: Is there any chance that an Exception is thrown?  With the empty `catch` block you would 'fall through' to the final `return` and see nothing indicating a problem.  Just a thought.

Comment: You should not have an empty `catch` like that.  At a bare minimum, you should be logging the error.

Comment: @IvanStoev I am working with async/await for the first time :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your continueWith. That runs on different thread. and you are returning something from that thread, not something from your original method.

What you really want is write your code like this

```
var r = await oneMoreAsyncCall()
if (r.IsCompleted == true)
{                   
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someData); // Hit second!
}
```

Comment: `oneMoreAsyncCall()` use a method `FindAsync()` that returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` so I don't have `IsCompleted` there.

Comment: @1110 You are correct you won't have the task after the await, but why do you need to check IsCompleted if you've already awaited the task.  You could always save the task in a variable and then await that, if needed.

Comment: @1110 The task will never not be completed when its continuation fires (awaiting it runs the subsequent code in a continuation) so your code is essentially  just `if(true){ ... }` which is identical to just omitting the `if`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the code with your suggestions and it works `var result = await AsyncMethodCall`. But I don't understand exactly what was the problem? If I use `await` is this wait for response like sync call?

Comment: @1110 No, it does not.  There are many thousands of tutorials on the topic, you can take your pick of resources with more information.  Of course, you really should have done that *before* you started using it.  If you had no idea what it even did, you shouldn't have been using it in the code that you originally had

Answer (score 1):

When using `async/await`, you don't have to use `ContinueWith` and check `IsCompleted` because the code after the `await` will be hit only when the awaited task is complete. Your code should be something like this

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SomeMethod()
{
   try
   {
       await login...;
       await doSomething....
       await oneMoreAsyncCall...
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someData);
   }
   catch {}

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther);
}
```